# Error de ejecución con FireStore en Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy intentando conectar mi aplicación con FireStore. Estoy siguiendo todos los pasos que se indican en la pestaña Tools/Firebase/Firestore/Read and write documents with Cloud Firestore. El problema es que al ejecutar mi aplicación obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 72403 > 65536).
```

Adjunto mi graddle:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bdfirestore"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
 }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error:

> `Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file`

ocurre por lo que explica la documentación en el apartado [***Cómo habilitar multidex para apps con métodos de más de 64 K***](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex?hl=es-419#avoid):

> Cuando tu app y las bibliotecas a las que hace referencia superan los
>   65,536 métodos, se produce un error de compilación que indica que tu
>   app alcanzó el límite de la arquitectura de compilación de Android...

A mi ocurrió eso hace poco en un proyecto a raíz de haber migrado a `androidx`. Por lo tanto es muy probable que la nueva plataforma use más métodos de modo que el límite de `65,536 métodos` es superado. Esos métodos no son solamente los de tu aplicación, sino los de todas las librerías que hayas incorporado a tu proyecto.

Dos soluciones son posibles: habilitar `multidex` o aplicar una política de reducción de métodos.

## 1. Habilitar `multidex`

Solamente tienes que modificar algunas configuraciones en el archivo: `app/build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...lo que tengas lo dejas tal cual y añades:
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
    ...lo que tengas lo dejas tal cual y añades:
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

### ¿Qué significa `multidex`?

La misma [documentación](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex?hl=es-419#avoid) lo explica claramente:

> Los archivos de las apps para Android (APK) contienen archivos de
>   códigos de byte ejecutables con formato de archivos Dalvik Executable
>   (DEX), que tienen el código compilado empleado para ejecutar tu app.
>   La especificación de Dalvik Executable limita la cantidad total de
>   métodos a los que se puede hacer referencia en un archivo DEX a
>   65,536, incluidos los métodos de marco de trabajo de Android, de
>   biblioteca y de tu propio código. En el contexto de la informática, el
>   término Kilo, K, denota 1024 (o 2^10). Como 65,536 es igual a 64 X
>   1024, este límite se denomina "límite de referencia de 64K".

Cuando habilitas `multidex` indicas que se puedan procesar varios archivos `DEX`.

## 2. Aplicar una política de reducción de métodos

Si quieres aplicar una política de reducción de métodos, puedes revisar las recomendaciones de Android en el apartado [***Cómo reducir, ofuscar y optimizar tu app***](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code?hl=es-419).

También puedes leer: [***Cómo evitar el límite de 64 K***](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex?hl=es-419#avoid)

Comment: ME FUNCIONÓ!!! No lo puedo creer. Estoy muy agradecido hermano :). Podrías decirme como te diste cuenta que faltaba eso? Me gustaría aprender a identificar que es lo que falta cuando se me presenten más situaciones como esta.

Comment: @TomasM Cuando migré mi proyecto a `androidx` me ocurrió un error parecido y lo resolví aplicando `multidex`. No tengo ahora a mano la documentación de la que me valí en su momento para resolverlo, por eso no la he puesto, te prometo buscarla y enriquecer la respuesta.

Comment: Que buena persona. Me alegra que haya gente tan predispuesta a ayudar en este hermoso mundo de la programación!

Comment: @TomasM he agregado más información y los enlaces correspondientes. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Agregando a la respuesta de @A.Cedano el error que te aparece de dex es por que sobrepasas la cantidad de metodos permitidos (65536) esto quiere decir que en tu build.gradle de modulo de aplicacion, seguramente agresate muchas dependencias o agregaste paquetes enteros con muchos metodos.

Por ejemplo, si vamos a usar el servicio de ubicacion de google play services hay dos formas de hacerlo

Una es agregar directamente todo play services a nuestra app

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

Lo que agregaria por ejemplo 50000+ metodos

O podes agregar simplemente de play services sola la libreria de ubicacion que es el que necesitas

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
```

el cual por ejemplo solo agregaria 100 metodos por ejemplo.

De esta forma prevenis problemas de dexing en tu app, esto es igual para todas las librerias, por ejemplo Firebase, cuando añadimos firebase-core en vez de cada elemento que necesitamos por separado.

Esto es el motivo por lo cual ocurren problemas de dex, y tenes que agregar el multidex si necesitas mas archivos dex

Basicamente como funciona es asi

Se crea una rchivo dex que contiene junto al bytecode te tu apk y sus metodos un limite de 65536 metodos para tu app, si esta cantidad se supera va a ocurrir un problema de dexing el cual te va a decir que no se puede alocar mas de lo que se puede en tu app. Es aca donde agregas multidex para crear no solo 1 sino x archivos dex necesarios para correr tu app, por lo que nunca tendras el problema de dex de nuevo, pero tampoco es recomendable usarlo siempre si no se necesita ya que corres un apk con muchisimos metodos que no necesitas, haciendo que su performance se redusca.

### El problema

### Cuando usas un minSdkVersion en 16 hasta 19

> Las versiones de la plataforma anteriores a Android 5.0 utilizan el
>   tiempo de ejecución Dalvik para ejecutar el código de la aplicación.
>   Por defecto, Dalvik limita las aplicaciones a un solo archivo de
>   código de bytes classes.dex por APK. Para evitar esta limitación,
>   puede usar la biblioteca de soporte multidex, que se convierte en
>   parte del archivo DEX primario de su aplicación y luego administra el
>   acceso a los archivos DEX adicionales y al código que contienen.

### Cuando usas un minSdkVersion en 20 en adelante

> Android 5.0 y superior utiliza un tiempo de ejecución llamado ART que
>   admite de forma nativa la carga de múltiples archivos dex desde
>   archivos APK de aplicaciones. ART realiza la precompilación en el
>   momento de la instalación de la aplicación que busca archivos de
>   clases (.. N) .dex y los compila en un solo archivo .oat para que el
>   dispositivo Android los ejecute. Para obtener más información sobre el
>   tiempo de ejecución de Android 5.0, consulte Introducción a ART.

**Documentacion ART :** https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art?hl=es-419

Por lo que si usas minSdkVersion >= 20 no vas a necesitar usar multidex en tu app

Comment: Que buena respuesta Gastón. Soy completamente ignorante en este tema y ahora me hiciste comprender algo totalmente nuevo para mi. Tu respuesta me resultó MUY útil. Podría pedirte entonces que revises el código de mi graddle app y me digas que librería está importando tantos métodos? Yo solamente agregué las de firebase. Este graddle es de un proyecto completamente vacío.

Comment: Hola Tomi, mira, todos arrancamos asi, no bajes los brazos que en este mundo todo es nuevo hasta incluso yo que hace 5 años que programo jaja, en tu gradle no veo que haya nada que importe tantos metodos por eso no respondi explicando lo de tu gradle, sino darte una explicacion a futuro si te pasa poniendo mas librerias

Comment: No quiero seguir molestándote pero tampoco quiero dejar esto sin comprenderlo: Por que entonces se me generaba el error si no tengo nada que importe tantos métodos?

Comment: el gradle que publicaste es tal cual lo tenes en tu proyecto ?

Comment: El problema lo acabo de ver, el minSdkversion lo tenes en 16, subilo a 21 - 22 y no deberias por que usar multidex

Comment: Si necesitas desde android 4.1 para arriba vas a tener que usar el multidex, pero es recomendable que empieces hoy en dia desde android 5.0 api 21 - 22

Comment: Gracias de nuevo Gastón. Cambié el minSdkVersion a 22 (me gustaría saber que es y para que sirve la versión sdk). Además, decirte que no entendí muy bien que me pedis en tu último comentario.

Comment: en tu gradle  minSdkVersion 16 si cambias eso por  minSdkVersion 20 no hace falta que uses mas multidex, como edite en mi respuesta en versiones viejas se requeria pero ahora a partir de android 5 no, el minSdkVersion sirve para que tu apk funcione en ciertos telefonos, en este caso si lo subis a 20 va a funcionar en telefonos con android 5 para arriba

Comment: Me costó un poco entender el edit aunque esté muy bueno y sea super didáctico. Se agradece un montón. Pero si no entendí mal, y espero me corrijas, las versiones de android superiores a 5.0 admiten más carpetas/archivos dex. Entonces al haber cambiado mi minSdkVersion lo que hice fue ir a una versión más alta para permitir más archivos dex pero aún así sigo teniendo más de 65.000 métodos . Esto es así?

Comment: puedes tener muchos archivos dex en versiones inferiores a 5.0 usando multidex como lo haces ahora, a partir de android 5 para arriba no te hace falta usar multidex ya que la forma de buildear es distinta

Comment: Creo que me expresé mal. Primero me ayudaron agregando multidex para soportar el sobrante de código importado gracias a alguna librería del modulo App. Después me decis que actualize mi versión para no usar multidex pero al actualizar, no borre/achiqué el  sobrante de métodos importados. Ya dije antes que tu respuesta como la de la otra persona me ayudaron pero creo que dejar mi aplicación así como está con tantos métodos importados, no va a ser para nada algo positivo. Me gustaría que alguien me ayude a encontrar que librería es la que importa tanto código para disminuir sus importaciones.